# Hide email password in python script

Tags: python, email, encryption, server, passwords

I create a python script using 'smtplib'. It needs to add a password as a variable. I need to connect it to a server to send scheduled emails. How to encrypt my password before connecting it to the server or is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to be able to decrypt the password afterwards?

Comment: The only thing is the password want to access the email. Besides that, I don't want to show it after someone opens the script when it is on the server.

Comment: If the server is shared and other users have access to your script, you won't b able to hide the pass.

Comment: Have you considered using something like the [dotenv lib](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)? A common way to obfuscate passwords and keys.